# a:hover not going full width on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

My problem is, that i am working on my first wordpress theme, by styling the _'s theme. I have been working on adding a dropdoown menu, the problem I am running into, is that if one of the dropdown item headers is too wide, then the a:hover color will not cover the full width of the contained items.

See contents within "A Really Long Header Width".

Sorry if my code is a little messy, still pretty new!

HTML

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu-guides-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-114"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/achievement-guides/">More Guides</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-11/">Guides 11</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-10/">Guides 10</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-8/">Guides 9</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-7/">Guides 7</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/map-completion-guides/">Another Dropdown Menu</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-15/">Guides 15</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-14/">Guides 14</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-13/">Guides 13</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-12/">Guides 12</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-64 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-109"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-6/">Guides 6</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-110"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-5/">Guides 5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-4/">Guides 4</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-3/">Guides 3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-2/">Guides 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-122"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16/">A Really Long Header Width</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16-2/">Guides 16</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16/">A Really Long Header Width</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8v5Lpdxg/

Comment: Your `.main-navigation ul ul a` css class is setting the anchor width to `200px` remove that and it should go full width (around line 44 of css in jsfiddle) [fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v5Lpdxg/3/)

Comment: That worked excellently for that specific problem, but, now the shorter items do not go full width :(.

Comment: To fix that, add `width: 100%;` to line 50 of the css

Comment: derp, I love you right now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the css line 44:

```
 .main-navigation ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
}
```

This forces any anchor tags to have a fixed width, removing that allows them to inherit the width 100%

Remove that and the menu items will be full width.

This will break the smaller menu items so you will also need to add the following to line 50:

```
.main-navigation ul ul li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This tells the sub menu list items to always be 100% (not just however wide the content is)

[See here for fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v5Lpdxg/4/)